# How to get the length of a file in MATLAB?

Tags: file, matlab, file-format

Is there any way to figure out the length of a .dat file (in terms of rows) without loading the file into the workspace?

Comment: How are "rows" defined for this file format? Is it a text file with one row per line, terminated by \n? Or fixed-length binary records? Or something else?

Answer (score 18):

Row Counter -- only loads one character per row:

```
Nrows = numel(textread('mydata.txt','%1c%*[^\n]'))
```

or file length (Matlab):

```
datfileh = fopen(fullfile(path, filename));
fseek(datfileh, 0,'eof');
filelength = ftell(datfileh);
fclose(datfileh);
```

Comment: This row counter is quite clean.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: testread will be removed in a future Matlab version. The corresponding version with textscan is *nrows = numel(cell2mat(textscan(fid,'%1c%*[^\n]')))*.

Comment: @YantaoXie, Alex K., this method is noticeably faster than just counting lines with `fgets()`. When processing a 1M lines telemetry file, it saves a few seconds.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you are working with text files, since you mentioned finding the number of rows. 
Here's one solution:

```
fid = fopen('your_file.dat','rt');
nLines = 0;
while (fgets(fid) ~= -1),
  nLines = nLines+1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

This uses [FGETS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fgets.html) to read each line, counting the number of lines it reads. Note that the data from the file is never saved to the workspace, it is simply used in the conditional check for the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth bearing in mind that you can use your file system's in-built commands, so on linux you could use the command

```
[s,w] = system('wc -l your_file.dat');
```

and then get the number of lines from the returned text (which is stored in `w`).  (I don't think there's an equivalent command under Windows.)

Comment: That way tyou'll get in s the return value of the command wc (i.e, 0 or different of zero) and in  w you'll an string with the number of lines concatenated with the name of the file. You need to separate them with [nlines fname] = strtok( w, ' ')