# Read data from a text file in MATLAB to different sized matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, text-parsing

Hi all I have a problem in matlab .

I have a text file in which the data is delimited by spaces. An example is given as follws :

```
3 4
1 3 6
2 4 5 7
1 3 0
0 0 -1 -2
1 -1 0 -1
-1 0 -2 0
1 -1  2 3 1
```

What I want to do is to read the text file & generate matrices like this :

```
size_mat=[3,4];
B=[1,3,6];
NB=[2,4,5,7];
b=[1,3,0];
A=[0, 0, -1, -2;
   1, -1, 0, -1;
  -1, 0, -2, 0];
z=[1,-1,2,3,1];

%//In details I can highlight these points : 
%//1st line is the size_mat matrix. This has always dimension 1X2. m=size_mat(1) & n=size_mat(2)
%//2nd line is the B matrix. Dimension is 1Xm 
%//3rd line is the NB matrix Dimension is 1Xn
%//4th line is the b matrix  Dimension is 1Xm
%//Starting from 5th line to the (last-1) line is my A matrix 
%//whose size is actually equal to mXn where m=size_mat(1) & n=size_mat(2)
%//Last line is the z matrix Dimension is 1X(n+1)
```

How can I do this matlab ?

Thanks in advance !!

Please do check the edits. Updated the sizes of the matrix to be extracted!

Comment: do you know something about the matrices in advance? Like, the fact that 1x2 is size_mat, 1x4 is NB, the first 1x3 is B...and on and on...? Because if you have no idea on how the file look like and how your matrices should look like in the end, then you can not do that exactly as you describe

Comment: I am editing the question. Please do look into it. The sizes of the matrices to be extracted are to be known beforehand. Specifically it is known from the first row itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it step by step:

1. First we read the lines as strings:

   ```
   fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
   C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
   fclose(fid);
   ```
2. Then we convert the lines into numerical values:

   ```
   C = cellfun(@str2num, C{:}, 'UniformOutput', false);
   ```
3. To group the values together into matrices, we could do something like so:

   ```
   size_mat = C{1};
   B = C{2};
   NB = C{3};
   b = C{4};
   A = vertcat(C{5:end - 1}); %// or: A = cell2mat(C(5:end - 1));
   z = C{end};
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not working with my dataset as the delimiter given in the file is "space". Do you know how can I get to work around it ??

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you trust your input file to be always structured like that, then you shall use fgetl(file_descriptor) to read your file line by line. Then you can split each line (string) using the white space as a delimiter.

Finally, for the matrix A, you just need to append the lines to that matrix until you get to the (last-1) line.

Comment: Is there anyway in which I can count the no of lines in the text file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945006/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-file-in-matlab