# Delete csv file matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

Is it possible to delete the contents of a CSV file in Matlab when the number of rows exceeds a certain parameter that I can set.

I am running a code multiple times, and each time it fills a row of my CSV file. I would like to contents to be deleted if there are more than 100 rows in my file (but not the file itself).

I use the code below:

```
parameters = [data1, data2, data3]
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile.csv', parameters, '-append')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not delete the file and recreate it with the same name?

Comment: That would work too actually but I am not sure how to delete the file

Comment: The confusingly named [`delete`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) might be one option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some kind of counter for running your code multiple times.
If so you could just go for

```
rowlimit=100;
if counter <= rowlimit;
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile.csv', parameters, '-append');
end;
```

So it stops writing to your file if the row limit is exceeded.

If you want the other rows at the beginning for some other reason you could also just write a second file only containing a hundred rows.

```
x=parameters(1:100,:);
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile2.csv', x, '-append');
```

It is just work arounds but the way you describe it, it does the trick for you.

**Edit**

If you want to delete the file and write it again as suggested in the comments.

Just go for:

```
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile.csv', parameters, '-append');
...
delete ('MYCSVFILE.csv');
parameters=parameters(1:100,:);
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile.csv', parameters, '-append');
```

Then you also have only a hundred lines.

**EDIT 2**

```
rowlimit=100;
if size(parameters,1) <=rowlimit
dlmwrite ('MyCSVFile.csv', parameters, '-append');
end;
```

Comment: None of this identifies how many lines are currently in the file.

Comment: well if you want to count the lines in your file, there are several posts on how to count lines in a csv or text file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945006/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-file-in-matlab - this one for example

Comment: Right, I ask because that was the whole point of his question. If you're not discarding the contents, "how do I stop writing at 100 lines" requires knowledge of the file, which is nowhere in your answer.

Comment: I edited the answer again, I hope that goes in the direction you meant.